# how to have Observer to be invoked at adapter init time?

Tags: android

I want to add an observer into an adapter to show an empty state ui when the adapter is empty, init adapter is just an empty state,but observers are not called without "notifyDataSetChanged()" method or something like that, is there a pattern to resolve this situation? or should i Manually invoke notifyDataSetChanged() method after i create the empty adapter? It's not a graceful solution i think...

Comment: I think you should look at `ListView.setEmptyView`

Comment: I need a pattern  to change ui all by data ,setEmptyView  is  a method to to be invoked to change the ui , not what i want, thanks